# p-triStateCheckbox not working in Angular6

Tags: primeng, angular6

PrimeNG p-triStateCheckbox's check and wrong images are not working in `Angular 6`.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: "not working" again... please explain it better.

Comment: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello! Welcome to *StackOverflow*. Please go through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question. Also, please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you have tried so far. Show some effort that you have put and I'm sure we'll be able to help you from there on.